# Post update hook fails to run via Drush, but works via update.php

Tags: 8, drush

I've implemented [hook_post_update_NAME](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_post_update_NAME/8.2.x) to bulk import some files into Drupal (creating file and media entities for them). This hook runs correctly when I use update.php. But it seems to silently fail via `drush updb`.

My update hooks looks like this

```
/**
 * Creates SVG icons as media entities.
 */
function my_module_default_content_post_update_create_icons() {

  $module_handler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
  $module_path = $module_handler->getModule('my_module_default_content')->getPath();

  \Drupal::logger('my_module_default_content')->notice('Importing icons from @path', ['@path' => $module_path]);

  $dir = new DirectoryIterator("$module_path/icons");

  \Drupal::logger('my_module_default_content')->notice('Directory contains @count items', ['@count', count($dir)]);

  foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {

      \Drupal::logger('my_module_default_content')->notice('Importing file @file', ['@file' => $fileinfo->getFilename()]);

      my_module_default_content_create_icon($fileinfo->getPathname());
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine via update.php. All the files are copied, relevant entities created, and messages logged to watchdog. When running `drush updb` I only get

> [ok] Update completed: my_module_default_content_post_update_create_icons
>
> [success] Finished performing updates.

None of my log messages are output (while using `--debug` option) to the screen or to watchdog.

My initial thought was a permissions issue, but if it's not outputting any of my log messages. I'm not positive the function is even being run. Adding in a `die()` on the first line of the function gave the exact same output/outcome.

Any ideas on what could cause this to silently fail when running via Drush?

Comment: I haven't done much development for D8, but I wonder: Where does `\Drupal::logger('my_module_default_content')->notice()` output the notice? I expected it to go to the normal Drupal log / recent log messages. Drush doesn't display those (and `--debug` isn't connected to `\Drupal::logger` logging). Have you checked recent log messages after running `drush updb`?

Comment: The messages do output to watchdog. Was able to confirm that when running it via `update.php`. No messages when running it via `drush updb`.

Comment: Another obvious comment: You are resetting the Drupal environment completely? I wonder because - from the docs: "Drupal also ensures to not execute the same hook_post_update_NAME() function twice." That could explain the lack of messages.

Comment: I was doing full DB drop and re-import between attempts. I've since re-worked the update hook to use the batch API to prevent timeout issues and run it via `update.php`. I suppose the question is academic at this point.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who runs into this, make sure that the post-update hooks are defined in a `MODULE_NAME.post_update.php` file. It seems as though `update.php` will happily invoke post-update hooks defined in the `MODULE_NAME.install` file, while Drush will not.